# Vaadin Push feature

Tags: java, spring, vaadin

I've ran into a strange problem using Vaadin. In my application I need to dynamicly push new data to the table viewed by the user. I've done some reading and it seems that I could achive just that with Vaadins' @Push feature.

But as soon as I've added the @Push annotation to my UI class everything stopped working. What I mean by this is I'm getting that message when accessing the UI

`Session Expired. Take note of any unsaved data, and click here or press ESC key to continue.`

clicking on the message just refreshes the whole page. 
I'm using Vaadin 8.0.6 and vaadingSpring 2.0.1, as well as Spring Boot 1.5.3

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Oh, I almost forgot. I've used this code as an example
https://github.com/peholmst/vaadin4spring/blob/master/samples/push-sample/src/main/java/org/vaadin/spring/samples/push/PushUI.java

Answer (score 2):

I found Push (with Spring) hard to configure. It was my fault, for sure, but I finally decided to drop it in favor of this simple extension which implements a client-based polling: https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/timerextension-add-on